# AWS Blue/Green stuck at "Replica creation is canceled due to external replication"

Tags: postgresql, aws-aurora

I'm trying to perform a Blue/Green upgrade of PostgreSQL 11.21 in AWS RDS.

The DB cluster has no replication slots. However every attempt failed in `Incompatible-create` state and the log message is "Replica creation is canceled due to external replication".

Nothing more. What could be the reason for this log message? There is no additional information, even Google doesn't have any result for this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After direct communication with the AWS support the reason was an existing [PUBLICATION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-publication.html).

That was missing in their pre-checks for PostgreSQL Blue/Green Upgrade.

The solution was simply to drop the existing `PUBLICATION`s via

```sql
DROP PUBLICTAION publication_name;
```